# IPFS daemon initialization

Tags: daemon, init, ipfs

I have been trying to initialize daemon but it asked for up-gradation which I did. Now when I try to initialize it it displays the following:
Error: Repo has incorrect version: 9
Program version is: 3
Please run the ipfs migration tool before continuing.
See https://github.com/ipfs/fs-repo-migrations/blob/master/run.md
Sorry for the inconvenience. In the future, these will run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to run just the latest version (currently 0.4.23) by checking `ipfs version`.

Login as the same user as the daemon process will run.

Make sure that the service file doesn't contain an IPFS_PATH environment variable pointing somewhere else than '~/.ipfs'.

Then move the old '~/.ipfs' folder - or the folder specified in the environment variable somewhere else. Then initialize IPFS again with something like `ipfs init --profile=badgerds`.

If you still run into issues, than print the debug log with the flag `--debug` and quote it here.